# Do only questions count as posts?

Tags: discussion, tags, posts

It seems like when I hover into my `Tags` section in my profile, I only see posts counting as questions. Shouldn't it count as answers as well?

I have 63 questions and 7 answers so shouldn't that be 70 posts in C#?

I know this is minor but I'm just curious that's all.

[image]

Comment: The numbers haven't been updating properly since January 22nd, so it's showing your post count from the last time it *was* updated. If you hover over the number at the left, it says 56 questions and 7 answers, which is where it gets the 63 total from. They're investigating a way to fix this.

Comment: @animuson Oh my bad. I thought sorry, it was just a coincidence with the number I misunderstood. You know what I mean right? I thought it didn't count the answers lol.